# I can't figure out why state is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make call to Unsplash API to return images based on location strings passed down from props.

When I console log this.state.props the response json object is there. But when I try to get the image urls off of state and use them as the source for an image, I keep getting an error that says "can't read property small of undefined".

Am I overlooking something?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Unsplash, {toJson} from 'unsplash-js';



const unsplash = new Unsplash({
  applicationId: {process.env.ID},
  secret: {process.env.SECRET},
  callbackUrl: {process.env.CALLBACK}
});


export default class Photos extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            photo:[]
        }


        this.getPhotos = this.getPhotos.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getPhotos();
      }

      getPhotos(){

          unsplash.search.photos(`${this.props.place}`,1,1)
          .then(toJson)
          .then(json => {
            this.setState({photo: json.results})
            console.log(this.state.photo)
          })


      }

      render(){

        return (
            <div>
                {

                 this.state.photo ? <img src = {this.state.photo.urls.small}/>:<div>loading</div>
                }

              </div>
              )
            }
}
```

Comment: what does `this.state.photo` actualy have in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.photo` is an array. An array does not have a property `urls` (therefore `undefined`). Trying to access the property `small` of `undefined` will raise the error.

You will have to loop through your photos and render each image. Example

```
render() {
  [...]
  this.state.photo.map((singlePhoto) => (
    <img src={singlePhoto.urls.small} />
  ))
  [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state needs to have the nested value set to something in order for this to work.

For instance,you are using `this.state.photo.urls.small` but your state is only an empty array.

One way to fix this would be to set it to null if this.state.photo is not defined. Also you might want to use this.state.photo.map  and a nested component instead of directly trying to access urls.

Example:

```
return (
    <div>
        this.state.photo.length ? this.state.photo.map(p => <div>
            <img src = {p.urls.small}/>
       </div>
       :<div>loading</div>
  </div>;
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can check if your array.length presents than use map on that array and each pic will be in callback of an array so you can use in img tag